# C++ Why is my newline being misinterpreted?

Tags: string, file, newline

I am writing a driver program in c++ that will eventually need to pass two strings to a function I am writing in a separate file. I am reading data from a  file that is formatted like this:

```
ac: and
amo: love
amor: love
animal: animal
annus: year
ante: before, in front of, previously
antiquus: ancient
ardeo: burn, be on fire, desire
arma: arms, weapons
atque: and
aurum: gold
aureus: golden, of gold
aurora: dawn
```

I'm trying to get the latin word into one string and the english equivalent in another string. Also, each time I get an english equivalent I want to be able to send the two strings to my function. My code currently looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//#include "tree.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string latinWord   = "",
           englishWord = "";

    char   buffer;

    bool   isLatinWord = true;

    ifstream vocabFile;
    vocabFile.open(argv[1]);

    if (!vocabFile)
       cout << "File open failed." << endl;

    while(vocabFile.get(buffer))
    {

        if (isLatinWord)
        {
            if (buffer == ':')
                isLatinWord = false;

            else
                latinWord+= buffer;
        }

        else
        {
            if (buffer == ',') // indicates 1 of multiple equivs processed
            {
                cout << englishWord << " = " << latinWord << endl;
                englishWord = "";
            }

            else if (buffer == '\n') // indicates all english equivs processed
            {
                cout << englishWord << " = " << latinWord << endl;
                isLatinWord = true;
                englishWord = latinWord = ""; // reset both strings
            }

            else
                englishWord+= buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

The way this SHOULD work is that if there is a colon, that symbolizes that the latin word string is finished populating (the flag is set to false) and then the english word string should start being populated. The english word string should be populated until a comma is hit (send the words to the function at this point), or a newline is hit (resetting the flag because all english equivs have been checked at this point).

However, when I try to output the strings I would send to my functions they are totally messed up.

This is my output:

```
$ ./prog5 latin.txt
 = ac
 = amo
 = amor
 = animal
 = annus
 before = ante
 in front of = ante
 = anteusly
 = antiquus
 burn = ardeo
 be on fire = ardeo
 = ardeo
 arms = arma
 = armas
 = atque
 = aurum
 golden = aureus
 = aureus
 = aurora
```

**[EDIT] This is my output after the isLatinWord flag was fixed.**
I'm thinking my code is recognizing newlines in a wrong way, and I was wondering if anyone sees any errors or has any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: One possibly higher level way of doing this is to read each line in the file.  Then "split" each line based on the ":" delimiter.  I would first make a function to read each line, although there is probably already one in the API and then I would write another function to separate the line at the colon, although there is probably already one in the API for that, too.

Comment: The very first read you do is a single character to `buffer`. This is a strange design and might explain some of the issues.

Answer (score 1):

New lines can be also represented as \r\n character, I would check for this as well.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is that the newline condition in the code is being considered true before it even gets to the first english word. Should I write some code to avoid the \r\n character?

Comment: The C++ library should, in theory, recognize whatever is the 'standard' newline sequence for the operating system you compile on. So, I think, you shouldn't have to consider it. But newlines on Windows are famously weird!

Comment: I would write a if statement for \r\n and let's see if this solves your issue, anyway @AaronMcDaid, yes you are right it should but with using the getline as you suggested below, not with buffer reading. and again, windows new lines can be freaky so even then I had seen it not working! :-/

Answer (score 0):

Using `getline` to read (parts of) lines up to a desired delimiter:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    ifstream data("data.txt");

    string latin_word;
    while(getline(data,latin_word,':')) { // Read up to, but not including, the colon. But it does *discard* the colon
        cout << "Read latin word: <" << latin_word << '>' << endl;
        // Read the rest of the line
        string rest_of_line;
        getline(data, rest_of_line);
        // Now, we want to split it on commas. Easiest way is to build a stream object wrapped around this string
        istringstream rest_of_line_stream(rest_of_line);
        string english_phrase;
        while(
                  rest_of_line_stream >> std:: ws, 
                  getline(rest_of_line_stream, english_phrase,',')
             ) {
            cout << '@' << latin_word << "@\t@" << english_phrase << '@' << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

*Update*: I had forgotten to discard enough whitespace. `getline` retains any leading whitespace by default. This can be a problem after the `:` and `,` in this data. Therefore, before any attempt to read an English phrase, I use `rest_of_line_stream >> std:: ws` to read and discard any whitespace.

The inner `while` loop might seem a bit strange. I have two things inside the `while` brackets: `rest_of_line_stream >> std:: ws`  and then `getline(rest_of_line_stream, english_phrase,',')`. The are separated by a comma and this is the *comma operator* in C and C++. Basically, it just means the first thing is evaluated but its result ignored. The boolean used for the while loop is then just the result of `getline(rest_of_line_stream, english_phrase,',')`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
latinWord = true;
```

should be

```
isLatinWord = true;
```

Comment: Thank you! It appears to have correct some of the logic, but still doesn't fix my newline problem, however. For some reason, a few english words are showing up fine, but the others are just blank!